# MySQL take difference between two fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query from which I am getting data.

```
SELECT n.`name`,n.`customer_id`,m.`msn`, m.kwh FROM mdc_node n
INNER JOIN `mdc_meters_data` m ON n.`customer_id` = m.`cust_id`
WHERE n.`lft` = 3 AND n.`icon` NOT IN ('folder')
AND m.`data_date_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

**Output**

[image]

Now I want to do is to subtract the `kwh` value like `kwh[2] - kwh[1]`, `kwh[3] - kwh[2]`, `kwh[4] - kwh[3]`..... `kwh[n+1] - kwh[n]`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) window function can be used for this problem as shown below,

```
SELECT n.`name`,n.`customer_id`,m.`msn`, m.kwh,
       m.kwh - LAG(m.kwh) OVER(PARTITION BY n.`customer_id` ORDER BY m.`data_date_time`)
FROM mdc_node n
INNER JOIN `mdc_meters_data` m ON n.`customer_id` = m.`cust_id`
WHERE n.`lft` = 3 AND n.`icon` NOT IN ('folder')
AND m.`data_date_time` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: I have posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608035/mysql-show-sum-of-difference-of-two-values) can you please see it?